# How to use NOSONAR at the end of the line having ESLINT and Prettier configured?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, sonarqube, eslint, prettier

Having `editor.formatOnSave = true` in VS code, when trying to ignore some rules and suppress the error using //NOSONAR at the end of the line. The line comment is going down. How and where these rules can be configured?

`export const overviewReducer = (state = initialState, action) => { //NOSONAR`

coming to the next line like:

`export const overviewReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {`

`//NOSONAR`

Answer (score 11):

I've just had the same issue.

Using `prettier-ignore` worked for me :

```
// prettier-ignore
export const overviewReducer = (state = initialState, action) => { //NOSONAR
```

Not the best solution, but at least it solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this issue I found googling "Prettier Nosonar"](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/2853), there's no workaround at this point – if Prettier decides a comment should move, it will damn well move it.

There's no whitelist of comments that should stay on the lines they're originally written on.

Comment: i also referred to this link: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/1267. Is there no such rules enabled yet?

Comment: That link tells you to use `// eslint-disable-next-line`, but as far as I know, there's no `// NOSONAR-NEXT-LINE`.

Comment: yes, i tried that and its not working. any work arounds?

Comment: Can we add default variables to sonar rules? Ex: `add(val=1)` is giving us sonar issues. How to configure the rule to accept defaults to methods?

Answer (score 0):

```
describe('VeryLongFunctionLintRuleOver200Lines', /* NOSONAR */ () => {
```

I was able to add comment like this so Prettier doesn't move it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).